# Looping Through Ember-Data Model Attrs in a Template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically loop through the `DS.attr`'s of an Ember-Data Model I've passed into a Component in Ember 2.0. Here's what I have:

Templates:

```
{{!person-component.hbs}}
{{each-in person as |property value|}}
  <tr>
    <th>
      <td>{{property}}</td>
      <td>{{value}}</td>
    </th>
  </tr>
{{/each-in}}

{{!index.hbs}}
{{person-component person=model}}
```

Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  "name": DS.attr('string'),
  "height": DS.attr('number'),
  "weight": DS.attr('number'),
});
```

Route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.find('person');
  }
});
```

Is there a simple way to do this from within handlebars? I was thinking possibly that a computed value on the controller might have to do it.

Comment: Where did you get that each-in from? Your code makes no sense.

Comment: It's new as of Ember 2.0.

Comment: Ah it's in the 2.1 beta, my bad didn't see the blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so `each-in` isn't designed to magically unbox Ember model attributes, only normal JSON objects. So the solution is to use controller logic which fetches a model's attributes. There might be a better way to do this, but this is the cleanest I've found in my limited experience with Ember.

```
// app/controllers/person.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  attributes: Ember.computed(function() {
    var attrNames = [];
    var person = this.get('person');

    // Get attributes
    person.eachAttribute((name) => attrNames.push(name));

    var attrs = Ember.getProperties(person, attrNames);
    return attrs;
  }),
});
```

If you implement this with the above code, everything works as expected as long as you modify the template to use `attributes` rather than `person`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work just fine, as long as you are using Ember 2.1 Beta. See the blog post about the new `each-in` helper.

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/08/16/ember-2-1-beta-released.html#toc_code-each-in-code-helper

This helper works exactly as you posted.

**Edit**

Actually, according to the comments, the `get` and `each-in` helpers actually snuck into Ember 2.0 (unannounced), see the comment here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/08/16/ember-2-1-beta-released.html#comment-2202060073, so no need to use the beta.